# Sublime Text 2 - HTML autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

In ST2 when you type `div.foo` and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> it goes to `<div class="foo"></div>`

Is there any setting to do autocompletion like that?

`<div class="foo">

    // 4spaces here.

</div>`

Thank you.

**UPDATED**

Didn't find a special setting but found where to change snippet if someone intested. 
In Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/html_completions.py just change

`snippet = "<{0} class=\"{1}\">$1$0".format(tag, arg)`

to

`snippet = "<{0} class=\"{1}\">\n\t$1\n$0".format(tag, arg)`

Solved.

Comment: Just hit `return` after you press `tab`

Comment: It doesn't work. When I press tab carriage sets right after the closing div.

Comment: are you using emmet? http://docs.emmet.io/

Answer (score 1):

You must be using emmet.... stock sublime text 2 does not auto complete class attribute from typing `element.class`  that is emmet's doing. I use it... I love that emmet magic.

Similarly you could type element>element to make the second one nest on the first one. or element#id to add an id instead of a class...

Here is an entire [cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) for emmet for more completions using emmet plugin on ST2.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page is on HTML. You can do this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Then type '**set html**'.

Then you can type **div.class_name** followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah, bit I need breakline between open and close tags.